# what does mean quasi-static channel

Tags: fading-channel, multipath, multi-channel

When I read papers about channels, I usually see something Quasi-static Channel,

Does "Quasi-static Channel" mean "time-variant channel" or "time-invariant channel"?

Comment: Hello Marcus, First, thank you for your downvoting !! .. Yes I understand what you mean but I need the answer to be in general. If I cited such reference the answer will be according to that citation. What I need is a general description. Exactly as below answers. Thank you for your understanding. please, cancel your downvoting.

Comment: sorry, that's dumb. "we need the answer to be in general". Great, so if I answer "quasi-static is when you have a bear dancing in front of your antenna", it's right, too? Because I wrote a paper where "quasi-static" means exactly that.

Comment: I.e. the answers you've gotten aren't "in general". They are just a specific understanding of the term, in a context that their authors don't mention. In that sense, they aren't correct at all.

Comment: @MarcusMüller ... I'm sorry of hearing that from you, you supposed to be here for helping others. Yes, sometimes I need that a description for such term in general. what's wrong

Comment: @MarcusMüller  .. Again, I usually read many useless comments for you. I'll tell here one again, it's not your task you evaluate others here, you should just help them if you can.  You must not answer or comment about all questions. You often give comments for questions which you don't know the answer. let others study and learn, and just try to guide them. please, please, please, let other students get benefit from this forum as much as possible and try just to guide them not to criticize them them.

Comment: I think that the motivation behind the question may have originated from the definition of the term itself. In general, anything ["quasi"](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+quasi) is "not exactly". Another example would be ["quasi real-time"](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=808553) systems. So, "quasi static" is time-variant with the rate (of change) being relatively slow. But how much and by how much depends on the application. "Quasi" originates in Latin, like "et al, i.e., a priori, de facto, in vivo" and others. From this point of view, the question would be off topic but...

Comment: ...certainly answerable in a comment or through [the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=dsp.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I am sorry, I voted to close the question too quickly from the review panel, without noticing that it had already receive an accepted answer. In any case, I have found [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/) a very useful and helpful community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quasi-static is almost-static. In other words, for a block (or window) period of time, you could assume that your channel is static. Below, i attach a figure that depicts this scenario. As you can see the channel could be assumed static for around 100 ms.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much .. got it. It means the channel is time invariant during block period but it might be time variant otherwise. we can say it's a special case of time-variant channel.

Comment: Yeah its as if you got piecewise static functions.

Answer (score 2):

Quasi-static channels are a "block-wise" time (in)variant. For example, your channel has no variations over time (not in the delay domain) for some time period(e.g., 1 ms), but the channel may change after 1 ms.

Comment: Thank you so much ..  got it. It means the channel is time invariant during block-wise but it might be time variant otherwise.